# Google Marketplace App - setting up test environments?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

In [Google Console](https://cloud.google.com/console/) I am configuring Google Drive SDK. On configuration page it asks for

`Open URL (This URL is used when the user opens an existing Google Drive item with your application)`.

[image]

It looks like I can only define only one URL, so how does one go about testing this functionality locally? I can switch the URL to point to a localhost but what if my app is already live and I need to debug locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of the problems with Drive that there is little support for dev/test environments.

The only solution I can think of for your specific question is around host name resolution. Something like ...

1. Register a subdomain, driveopenhost.example.com
2. Have the DNS for driveopenhost cname to your actual host (eg. www.example.com)
3. On your development PC, configure /etc/hosts (or the windows equivalent) to resolve driveopenhost.example.com to 127.0.0.1

Comment: `hosts` file is probably the easiest solution for me. Thank you. Google Marketplace set up environment process - for developers - seems half baked and scattered.